# Unable to correct GPS projection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, gps

I have a shapefile of a line feature created using GPS. The coordinate system and projection info on the original is:

NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_10N (this is in meters)
WKID: 26910 Authority: EPSG
Projection: Transverse_Mercator
Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_North_American_1983

Extent:
**Left:** 511231.976300 m
**Right:** 512950.095100 m
**Top:** 4210505.853400 m
**Bottom:** 4207483.315300 m

The result looks like this:
[image: Offset from projection issue]

where there is an offset of 200-300 meters. I have tried various projections in the data frame and have used the define projection tool to get the path to line up, but this is as close as it will come. What should my next steps be to get this to line up? Here is a download link for the shapefile (it's very small): https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BxJnXRpaO3M2TUJiVU85SGhkd1k?usp=sharing.

Comment: Any chance of a copy of your data? Even just that bit of the path?

Comment: I have uploaded a shapefile to a google folder here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BxJnXRpaO3M2TUJiVU85SGhkd1k?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data appears to have been digitised with epsg:26710 coordinates, which is UTM zone 10N based on the NAD27 datum.

If I assign that projection to your data - note I'm not *reprojecting* it, I'm setting the projection to epsg:26710 - then I get a very good alignment with the feature on OpenStreetMap. See image, where green line is the feature in epsg:26710, and the line wandering off into the sea is your original projection.

[image]

I tried the other UTM 10N projections as well, but this is easily the closest to the feature on OpenStreetMap. Note you can hardly see the feature on OpenStreetMap in the image because the green line feature is so close to it!

The easiest way to change the projection is probably just to replace the .prj file with this (although I might have messed it up pasting it here)

```
PROJCS["NAD_1927_UTM_Zone_10N",
 GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1927",
   DATUM["D_North_American_1927",
   SPHEROID["Clarke_1866",6378206.4,294.9786982]],
   PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
   UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
   PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-123],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["Meter",1]]
```